# Aks for price button

Tags: social-buttons

quick description: I got products which are not allowed to be put online with discount.
so I need to find a different solution to offer the customers the lowest price (see example from my product vieuw bellow)

My idea: I can put an extra button on the product view which will say something as: quotation or ask for special price And link it to a new / special form. Instead of the crossed AVP price with my big red price  as shown on the picture bellow.

Does someone have an better idea? Or got some info what I can read to get the extra button done and or the extra form? (I am a newbie on this but if I got the right information I can make it)

[image: verwarmland]

Answer (score 0):

Try this Extension

```
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/call-for-price-9.html
```

It will help you

Or

Create One Yes/No Attribute and Follow this

```
  <!-- Call For Price - begin -->
            <?php $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('call_for_price'); ?>
                <?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
                <?php if ($attribute_value == 'Yes'): ?>
                    //Please Call for pricing
                <?php else: ?>
                 // Add to cart Button Code
 <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- Call For Price - end -->
```

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. I watched the plug-in but this will remove the price and the add to card. this should not happen. it’s just optional if someone got a special price quotation from some shop so that I can give the same price on the shop. about the yes/no attribute to what file do I need to add this? as I told u I am e newbie on this. (maybe there is a tread where is described?)

Comment: I think you just need to add the attribute in your Magento backend under Catalogue > Attributes > Manage Attributes.. and then you can access it with this code

Comment: Yes you can create Catalogue > Attributes > Manage Attributes then you can use this also add form for getting details from customer end